# Exception while persisting JPA object in DB having one to many relation

Tags: jpa

hi have two tables in picture table a and table b as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "JOURNAL_CATEGORY_ID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "clm_jounal_category_config_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "JOURNAL_CATEGORY_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "CLAIM_ID")
    private String claimId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "country")
    private List<ClaimDTLS> claimDetails;
}

B Primary Key:

@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "CLAIM_ID")
    private String claimId;
}

B Entity:

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B  implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected BPK bpk;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @MapsId("country_code")
    @JoinColumn(name = "claimId", referencedColumnName = "claimId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}
```

when i try to persist object of A type in Db the value of table b claim id is not set and is intialized with zero.
    Also primary key of table A is generated with a oracle sequence.

```
any help will be welcomed.
thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequence values are numbers and when JPA use them as a generator it call the setter method of the entity PK. Now, you defined your PK as a string while you use a sequence and so no matching setter can be found. Change the type of you PK to be Long and things shall work